# javascript regexp slow with special characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, replace

I have spent the last two days trying to figure out something and I would really appreciate if someone could explain that to me.

edit: I finally understood that the issue is not so much because of the code below, but it coming from a library that I use to load the regexp, the package xlsx. If I load the regexp from with another way the problem does not happen.

---

**This question is now obsolete, I keep it for reference. I will post a question specific to xlsx pakcage separately**

I have an array of objects (about 150k) like that:

```
[
  {regexp: 'something (either|or) anything', res: 'result is: $1'},
  {regexp: 'or something more complexe ....', res: '...'},
  ...
]
```

Each object contains two properties:
  1. regexp: regexp to search for
  2. res: text to replace with

So for example, it could be:

1. this is (good|bad) news
2. result is: $1

and I'm using this arrays like this: provided an input string, for each obj, I do a replace on the string

```
function doSomethingOn(text) {
    regexpObjs.forEach(regexpObj => {
        text = text.replace(regexpObj.regexp, regexpObj.regexpRes);
    });
    return text;
});
```

I have noticed that the first time I run doSomethingOn for a string, it will take "a long time". I suppose it is the time the runtime will take to compile and cache the regexp. Then any further call to doSomethingOn with the same string, or any other character string will be much faster

My problem and question is the following:
  - If now as an input string I use a string with a special character, such as ’ , “, » or «, etc... the the first time it will again take a very long time.

Worse, in some cases, the next time I run doSomethingOn with any string will crash with "FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory"

Question 1: why is the execution time with a string with a special character takes a long time the first time

Question 2: what could make it crash later after the call with a special character string

As a complement, here is an example of timing in milliseconds with 150k relatively complex regexp in one run:

1. time with char string 1 = **6017ms**
2. time with char string 1 = 184ms
3. time with char string 2 = 178ms
4. time with special char string 1 = **4040ms**
5. time with special char string 1 = 282ms
6. time with char string 1 = 180ms
7. time with char string 2 = 182ms

Comment: Hello, I have updated the question because I figured out that the crash was not so much due to the code above, but to a library that I use to load the regexp. See in the question directly